# Quicksort's strange behaviour when sorting descending-ascending data

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

Why this implementation of qs works as below, when sorting array containings numbers in descending-ascending order (100, 99, .., 0, 99, 100)?:

```
time for 50000 elements: 0.123 s
time for 100000 elements: 0.288 s
time for 150000 elements: 0.629 s
time for 200000 elements: 0.695 s
time for 250000 elements: 1.652 s
time for 300000 elements: 1.663 s
time for 350000 elements: 3.404 s
time for 400000 elements: 4.185 s
time for 450000 elements: 3.887 s
time for 500000 elements: 6.73 s
time for 550000 elements: 8.887 s
time for 600000 elements: 9.137 s
time for 650000 elements: 11.094 s
time for 700000 elements: 8.436 s
time for 750000 elements: 15.182 s
```

It works faster for 700000 elements than for 650000 elements. I repeated the test several times.
Here is the code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <new>
    #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;
    inline void swap (int *a, int *b)
    {
        int tmp;
        tmp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = tmp;
    }
    void quick_sort(int tab[], int l, int r);
    int *allocate (int size);
    void dec_inc (int tab[], const int length);
    int main()
    {
        int step = 50000;
        int how_many = 15;
        int k = 1;
        int length = step * how_many;
        int *tab = allocate(length);
        clock_t t2, t1;
        long double dif;
        while (step * k <= length)
        {
            dec_inc(tab, step*k);
            t1 = clock();
            quick_sort(tab, 0, step*k - 1);
            t2 = clock();
            dif = (long double)(t2 - t1)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
            cout << "time for " << step * k << " elements: " << dif << " s" << endl;
            k++;
        }
        delete [] tab;
        system("pause");

    }
    int *allocate (int size)
    {
        try
        {
            return new int [size];
        }
        catch(bad_alloc)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
    void quick_sort(int tab[], int l, int r)
    {
        int v = tab[(l+r)/2];
        int i = l;
        int j = r;
        do
        {
            while(tab[i] < v) i++;
            while(tab[j] > v) j--;
            if (i <= j)
            {
                swap(&tab[i], &tab[j]);
                i++, j--;
            }
        }
        while(i <= j);
        if (l < j)
            quick_sort(tab, l, j);
        if(i < r)
            quick_sort(tab, i, r);
    }
    void dec_inc (int tab[], const int length)
    {
        int i = length/2;
        for (int j = 0; j < length/2; j++, i--)
        {
            tab[j] = i;
        }
        for (int j = length/2; j < length; j++, i++)
        {
            tab[j] = i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you run this more than once to see if it was not a blip in the data.  ie other process stopped so for that part of the execution there were more system resources available.

Comment: I run this several times. Similar deviations occured.

Comment: Would you mid sharing the full code that produces this output so I can run it?

Comment: This almost certainly has to do with caching and/or virtual memory. You can instrument the code to count how many times the `quick_sort` function and the `swap` function are called, and there's nothing unexpected going on. The counts increase by `n log(n)` as you increase the length of the array.

Comment: I could be missing something but where to you actually initialize the elements of the array?  Using uninitialized data is undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3386109 You're right. The number of swap and quic_sort calls grows steadily. It's strange that similar deviations doesn't occur when sorting random numbers. And it happens always in the same place: 350000, 400000, 450000 and 650000, 700000, 750000.

Comment: @NathanOliver Look at function dec_inc()

Comment: I knew I had to missing it.  Thanks.

Comment: I get the same results.  The only think I can think is it hit some sort of magic value that makes the algo run more efficiently.

Comment: There are a lot of weird effects inside of CPUs.  For example branch prediction.  Those while loops are going to flip between predictions of always being true to always being false.  When the prediction is right for the values, things run faster.  When it is wrong, you'll get a chain of pipeline stalls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the drawbacks of using quicksort is its stability. Certain data sets need more steps to be sorted than others. For pathological cases it may even scale as O(n^2). I measured the number of comparisons performed by quicksort for your test data and saw that at with 700000 steps there are less comparisons to be performed than with 650000 elements. Even though your data sets seem similar, apparently for quicksort they are not. There are ways to improve quicksort's stability, see for example [Programming Pearls](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Programming_Pearls.html?id=kse_7qbWbjsC&redir_esc=y).

Here are the measurements:

time for 650000 elements: 4.41251 s. num. comparisions 5061169826

time for 700000 elements: 3.37787 s. num. comparisions 3824058435

time for 750000 elements: 6.07856 s. num. comparisions 6900645055

And here the corresponding code: [gist](https://gist.github.com/barmettl/497b50ff89c792c4fb65b0d327838685)

Comment: Your code overflows int! your results are incorrect.

Comment: Oh, nvm looks like in your compiler long = long long, in mine its long = int so +1

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this overflow issue. Changed the code accordingly.

Comment: @pbarmettler "Even though your data sets seem similar, apparently for quicksort they are not. " But why? Pivot point is always 0, so why is the number of comparisions decreasing?

Comment: I do not see how the pivot point can always be at 0 in your case. If you expect that your quicksort algorithm should be behave in a certain way, it may be useful to analyze the output after each step using small examples. It is interesting to see that the drop in comparison count also happens with very small vectors, e.g. size 10 and size 14. You may learn something from these cases.

Comment: @maksym pivot point is not always 0, that's not true at all, you should "run" your algorithm on paper.

Comment: @paulpaul1076 I was talking about the starting point. Sorry for being unclear.